# show files at a URL

Tags: java, file, url

I have 2 application deployed on my server and first application is suppose to list the files in a folder in another application.

But the problem is these two application may be deployed on 2 different physical servers. So is it possible to fetch the files from the URL

i.e is there a way something like

```
List<file> getFileList(<URL>/folderName) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible by HTTP. Use FTP or let the server platform mount it on the local disk file system.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, I just wanted to make sure this isn't possible. Actually First application uses some url from another application to display pdf files like http<URL>/folderName/xxx.pdf & there are some 4 - 5 different pdf. Name of the pdf is pretty tuff to be guessed but i had this other concern that i mentioned above...

Answer (score 0):

As @BalusC said, by HTTP it is not possible... unless you write a special script of your own returning a list of files in the folder you need (with permissions check, of course).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. as per my comment to @BalusC reply, i would have been more concerned if this would have been possible directly.